# Validar Documento de Identidad en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como validar que el texto ingresado tiene un formato correcto, sabiendo que el numero de documento tiene el siguiente formato `12345678-9`?

He probado por la longitud de la cadena pero aun me falta obligar al usuario que ingrese el guion, no he encontrado una referencia sobre mascaras en `android`.

```
String docIdentificacion= titDuiCon.getText().toString().trim();
  if(docIdentificacion.length<11){
      //aqui muestro un error
  }
```

Comment: Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es con este plugin es fácil de usar y cumpliría tu cometido. [https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext) Así evitas tener que realizar la comprobación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías realizar la comprobación a través de una expresión regular,[aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) encuentras mayor explicación de las reglas:

```
String dniString="^\\d{8}+-\\d{1}";
Pattern dniPattern=Pattern.compile(dniString);
Matcher matcher=dniPattern.matcher(docIdentificacion);
if(matcher.matches()){
   //Código de validación confirmada
}
else{
   // No se valido correctamente
}
```

Para tu caso sería del tipo ^\d{8}+-\d{1}  porque contiene 8 dígitos de inicio (^\d{8}) luego lo sigue un -  y luego va otro dígito (\d{1}).

Usando android Studio hay una caracteristica muy interesante,te ubicas en la expresión y le das Alt+Enter y te aparecerá una opción "Check RegExp" en la cual podrás ir probando si un valor concuerta con la expresión que tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias realizarlo de la siguiente manera

Usa `contains("-")` para verificar que el String contenga el `-`

```
String docIdentificacion= titDuiCon.getText().toString().trim();
if(docIdentificacion.length<11 && !docIdentificacion.contains("-"){
      //aqui muestro un error
  }
```